# Switching wordpress site to another domain on ubuntu server

Tags: wordpress

I have an ubuntu server with apache and I have created a WordPress site, I want to switch it to another domain.  of my site been called siteA I would like to call it siteB. Will making changes to my site config file be enough and in wordpress, I change the permalinks in WordPress will I have to change the wp-config or I can leave it?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName siteA.com
        ServerAlias siteA.com *.siteA.com siteB.com *.siteB.com
        <Directory /var/www/siteA>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/siteA

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =*.siteA.co.za [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =siteA.co.za
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =*.siteB.co.za [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =siteB.co.za
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

to avoid redirect issues, you should either
a) update wp-options table and adjust `home` and `siteurl`
b) define your new domain in wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

Note that defining constants in wp-config will override home/siteurl settings in the DB.

After rebuilding permalinks, your posts and file attachments should resolve as expected. 
Note, that some plugins do not follow best practices. I.e. instead of storing a shortcode like `[attachmentid=2]` it may embed a string of an absolute path directly in a WYSIWYG editor.

I recommend using this tool: 
https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

...which will do a robust search and replace through your database for hard coded path strings.

As a tip, your browser may cache DNS resolutions. If you have followed these steps and still getting redirect issues when trying to login, try appending a dummy GET parameter to  the new URL, like ?dummy=wqwehb